# Browsing 'Decorated Names' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, name-decoration

I'm working on a (rather horrible) project that involves importing a C++ class hierarchy through a dll interface.  One of the more horrible details requires me know the 'decorated' names for the various class elements that are exposed - mostly member functions and static data.

There are *many* ways to achieve this - the assembly listing or map file, dumpbin, a dependency walker, the _*FUNCDNAME*_ macro, etc.  Unfortunately, they all require me to actually compile the code or have the compiled dll - and all I have available is the header files.  (That may leave you scratching your head for a minute - just take my word that it truly is a horrible project.)

Now, I can easily concoct something compilable from just the headers and use one of the above approaches.  But if I can avoid it, that would be much better.  So my question is: is there a way to browse decorated symbol names from within Visual Studio, a la Object Browser?  I know that the decoration is technically done at compile time, but Intellisense does so many other things while you type that I'm hoping it might do this too.

Comment: No, you have to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fail take that .h, rename it to .cpp, replace all semicolons (;) with

```
{
#pragma message(__FUNCDNAME__)
}
```

edit it a little, and compile it. You'll get your list.

Comment: Thanks.  It doesn't help me with the static members, but it's more efficient than outputting to a file for member methods.